# materializecss chips onChipAdd callback not working

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm writing a form field using materializecss that contains `mat-chips` with the autocomplete option. The idea is to do a `PATCH` request whenever a new chip is added. Below is the code snippet I'm currently using:

```
$('#tag-chips').material_chip({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            data: {
                'golang': null,
                'docker': null,
                'kubernetes': null
            }
        },
        onChipAdd: () => {
            console.log('tag added');
        }
    });
```

The chip field works perfectly but the callback never seems to fire up. Also there is no error message in the console either.

I've also tried the other way to achieve this based on a few searches I did which suggested:

```
$('#tag-chips').on('chip.add', (event, chip) => {
        console.log(event, chip);
});
```

But to no help.

Answer (score 3):

ES6 way using arrow function, you can call functions like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="chips chips-autocomplete"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            data: {
                'Apple': null,
                'Microsoft': null,
                'Google': null
            },
            limit: Infinity,
            minLength: 1
        },
        onChipAdd: () => {
            console.log("Chip Added");
        },
        onChipSelect: () => {
            console.log("Chip Selected");
        },
        onChipDelete: () => {
            console.log("Chip Deleted");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I have a working example. Call the callback like so:

```
onChipAdd: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

```js
$('.chips-initial').chips({
    autocompleteOptions: {
        data: {
            'golang': null,
            'docker': null,
            'kubernetes': null
        }
    },
    onChipAdd: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    
<!-- Default with no input (automatically generated)  -->
  <div class="chips chips-initial"></div>
```

Comment: Same for `on('chip.add'`.